# Workflow approval task is not listed in 'Project Server Workflow Tasks' list.

Tags: sharepoint-workflow, ms-project-server-2013

I have created a custom approval workflow in project server 2013. When the project reaches to its approval point. The approval item is not visible in the 'Project Server Workflow Tasks' list.

But when I go to Project Center-> Select Project-> Additional Workflow Data in All workflow stages it is showing the task there with proper assigned to resource.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue so that the approver can see his pending workflow task in 'Project Server Workflow Tasks' list.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.. The default view was late task that is why my workflow task were not listed in the 'Project Server Workflow Tasks' list. When I change the current view my pending task were all correctly showing in the list.